# React Imask enum mask dont work what could be the problem?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, vue.js, imaskjs

The problem is that the mask I use does not work correctly and I do not understand what the error is, that is, I can enter different values, but not exactly those listed, what is the problem? I write the code in React, but I think it’s not important

```
mask: '{\\03}T000000000000000',
    lazy: false,
    blocks: {
        T: {
            mask: IMask?.MaskedEnum,
            enum: ['100','212', '222', '232', '242', '252', '262', '272', '214', '224', '234', '254'],
        },
    },
```